# What is Django ORM equivalent for sql "field <> 1"?

Tags: sql, django, postgresql, django-orm

Assuming that `field` is nullable, in raw SQL condition

```sql
WHERE field <> 1
```

will exclude all `1` rows and also **exclude** all `NULL` rows.

Why Django `~Q(field=1)` makes query

```sql
WHERE (NOT (field = 1 AND field IS NOT NULL))
```

which results to **include** `NULL` rows. Is there equivalent for SQL `field <> 1` in Django ORM?

Answer (score 0):

Because Django's interpretation makes more sense from a Python developer's point of view. SQL has separate constructs for checking for null values (`IS NULL` and `IS NOT NULL`), and both `field == NULL` and `field <> NULL` are `NULL` (neither `true` nor `false`), which is not exactly intuitive.

Think of it this way: If I want to get all rows where `field <> 1` I probably want to get rows with `NULL` values as well because `NULL` is not `1`.

If you want to replicate the same behaviour you can use something like

```py
MyModel.objects.exclude(field=1).exclude(field__isnull=True)
```

Comment: This will make
`WHERE (NOT (field = 1 AND field IS NOT NULL) AND NOT (field IS NULL))`
which still results to include `NULL` rows.

Comment: So probably only `~Q(field=1) & Q(field__isnull=False)` behaves as SQL `field <> 1`

Comment: If you use it a lot you can write a function `sqlne( fieldname, value)` to return masb's Q-expression `~Q(**{field:value} ) & Q(**{ f"{field}__isnull":False} )`

Comment: @masb No, it will only return non-NULL values that are different from `1`. In fact, the only difference with your `~Q` version is mine generates a `NOT (field IS NULL)` while yours translates to `field IS NOT NULL`.